# Solvability of a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Applying numerical discretization my problem leads to:
$(A+\mu B)v=c$
where $A$ and $B$ are known real valued square matrices ($N\times N$), $c$ is a known vector, $\mu$ is an unknown parameter (physically should be real), and $v$ is an unknown vector. For what $\mu$ values is the equation solvable?

My idea is to calculate the generalized eigenvalue problem for $A$ and $B$, but I am unsure how to interpret the result.

Comment: What is the question exactly? The generalized eigenvalue problem finds when $A-\lambda B$ is not invertible. So unless $\mu$ is the negative of one of these, then $v=(A+\mu B)^{-1}c$.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer. So, the equation system is solvable in the case of any $\mu$, that is not equal to $-\lambda_i$.